# Почему у дополнений, отвечающих на предложные вопросы, отсутствуют предлоги

Tags: падежи, синтаксический-разбор, сказуемые, дополнение

Проведем разбор предложения по учебнику:

> Я отучил его (от чего?) от экономии (дополнение). Я отучил его (от чего?) экономить (дополнение).

В обычной речи, ответ на вопрос: **От чего ты его отучил?** **-Экономить.** Звучит странно. Так почему же этот ответ принимается при разборе предложений? Ведь у **экономить** даже предлога нету, чтобы отвечать на такой вопрос. Правильно было бы: **Я отучил его от экономить (дополнение)**.

Answer (score 2):

```
  Почему у дополнений, отвечающих на предложные вопросы, отсутствуют предлоги?
```

Потому что эти дополнения выражены неизменяемой частью речи - инфинитивом, он не имеет формы падежа, а предлог указывает на падеж. В этом словосочетании не управление, а примыкание.

А вопрос может быть двойной: От чего ты его отучил? Ты его отучил что делать? Первый вопрос к члену предложения, второй - к части речи, чтобы сохранить логику Вашей "обычной речи".

Comment: Так можно сказать, что вопрос "от чего ты его отучил" к "экономить", притянут за уши. Типа "дополнение" на него не отвечает и точка. Значит оно и не является дополнением. Не знаю как там в английском. Наверное русистика старается копировать англистику как может.

Comment: Ну, да, именно для этого, но, надеюсь, другим членом предложения Вы его не назовёте? Сказуемым он не будет, потому что действие экономить будет производить не субъект, обозначенный как ТЫ, а объект, тот, которого научили.

Comment: Что ж, попробуйте совершить такой переворот, но пока Я мечтаю петь - сказуемое, а в "Я научу тебя петь"  научу сказуемое, а петь - дополнение. Логика: (Кто?) Я (что сделаю?) научу (чему научу? что делать?) петь. А в первом примере я мечтаю и я буду петь - оба действия исполняет субъект, но одно главное, а второе вспомогательное.

Comment: "Я отучил его от того чтобы экономить" -- А это сложно-подчиненное предложение? Я бы сказал что "Я отучил его экономить" это урезанная версия "Я отучил его от того чтобы экономить"

Comment: Русский язык богат, можно сказать по-разному, но это будет другая конструкция и другой анализ